# Boolean Algebraic Simplification

Tags: java, boolean, algebra, simplification

So, I have several of these questions. I just need help on one of them. Also would you provide the explanation to how you got your answer. I would be very much appreciated

Show the algebraic simplification of ab(!c) + !ab(!c) to b(!c).

Comment: If you're looking for a program which will solve it in Java, then show some effort. If you just want to simplify it, then you're on the wrong site as it is just math. Check here: http://sce.umkc.edu/~hieberm/281_new/lectures/forms-of-bool-expressions/forms-of-exprs.html and here http://sce.umkc.edu/~hieberm/281_new/lectures/simplification/simplification.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created three variables as per your needs and have chosen random values.

```
boolean a=true;
boolean b=false;
boolean c=true;

boolean res1;
boolean res2;
boolean final_Res;

res1=(a && b) &&(!c) || (!a && b && !c);
res2=(b && !c);
final_Res=res1==res2;
System.out.println(final_Res);
```

Hope this helps to solve your other problems..